# unable to get specific data from json object

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get the value for acquired and assign it to $acquired. I've tried  `$acquired = $content['response']['item_json']['acquired'];`
without success. Below demonstrates the sample data and how I've tried to retrieve it.

```
<?php

// sample data from curl call
$result = '{"response":{"item_json":"[{ \"accountid\":\"123\",\"itemid\":\"456\",\"quantity\":1,\"originalitemid\":\"789\",\"itemdefid\":\"100\",\"appid\":101112,\"acquired\":\"20210921T175213Z\",\"state\":\"\",\"origin\":\"external\",\"state_changed_timestamp\":\"20210921T175213Z\" }]"}}';

// lets work with this data

$content = json_decode($result['response']['item_json']['acquired'], true);

var_dump($content);

?>
```

Comment: [this](https://3v4l.org/O8n1t) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item_json` is a nested JSON string, you need to decode it.

```
$content = json_decode($result, true);
$result2 = json_decode($content['response']['item_json'], true);
var_dump($result2);
```

Comment: I updated my code per your recommendation (above) and I'm getting:

PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'response' 
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'item_json'

Comment: I was basing my answer on what you showed in `var_dump($content)`.

Comment: How do I get ['acquired']?

Comment: `$result2[0]['acquired']`

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
$content = json_decode($result, true);
$result2 = json_decode($content['response'], true);
$result3 = json_decode($result2['item_json'], true);
var_dump($result3);
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in on line 9
NULL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).